# CakePHP v2 Domain Username without auth?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on a small internal site ( = users are logged onto their machines with domain credentials). On "standard" PHP get_current_user() works like a charm, in cake it doesn't. I'm trying to find a way that I can get the username without triggering the Auth component/a full login dialog as the user is already logged in.

Every suggestion/thread I've seen involves the Auth component and it's really cumbersome.

**EDIT:** get_current_user() returns "root", I presume this could be because of the routing or something internal/intentional?

Thanks!

Comment: CakePHP is still PHP in the end, so why is `get_current_user()` not an option? What happens when you try it? Does it give an error?

Comment: Updated my question, it returns "root"...

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you can use `get_current_user()` for user authentication. As per the PHP manual it "Gets the name of the owner of the current PHP script". Now the script owner (user which created the php file) is always going to be the same regardless of who accesses it.

Plus as Oldskool said above CakePHP is still PHP.